# JQuery - Default fail() function for ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have following code:

```
    $.get('somescript.php', callback_fn).fail(function(){ alert("Error message!"); });
    $.get('somescript2.php', callback_fn2).fail(function(){ alert("Error message!"); });
    $.get('somescript3.php', callback_fn3).fail(function(){ alert("Error message!"); });
```

**The fail function is always the same.**

I want to do this and still show the fail error, is it possible?

```
    $.get('somescript.php', callback_fn);  
    $.get('somescript2.php', callback_fn);
    $.get('somescript3.php', callback_fn);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$(document).ajaxError` as a solution.

```js
// Requests
$.get('somescript.php', callback_fn);
$.get('somescript2.php', callback_fn);
$.get('somescript3.php', callback_fn);

// Mock function
var callback_fn = function() {
  // does nothing yet 
}

// This is the key to the solution
$(document).ajaxError(function(){
  alert('error');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```js
$.getJSON('somescript.php')
        .done(function() { alert('request successful'); })
        .fail(function() { alert('Error message!'); });

$.getJSON('somescript2.php')
        .done(function() { alert('request successful'); })
        .fail(function() { alert('Error message!'); });
        
$.getJSON('somescript3.php')
        .done(function() { alert('request successful'); })
        .fail(function() { alert('Error message!'); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```